# Generating random string from array then remove it so it wont regenerate

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, random

```
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int randomArray = (int) (Math.random() *4);
    textView1.setText(questions[randomArray][0]);
```

Using the code above (using Android Studio to develop an app) I can generate a random question from my array as shown below.

```
 String[][] question= new String[20][5];

 {
     question[0][0] = "what is my name?";
     question[0][1] = "Mark";
     question[0][2] = "Steven";
     question[0][3] = "Alan";
     question[0][4] = "Bob";

     question[1][0] = "what is my age?";
     question[1][1] = "30";
     question[1][2] = "31";
     question[1][3] = "32";
     question[1][4] = "33";
 }
```

The code below shows how I allocate the answers to the buttons so that they randomize to different buttons each time:

```
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    int randomArray1 = (int) (Math.random() *4);
    button2.setText(questions[randomArray][randomArray1+1]);

    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    int randomArray2 = (int) (Math.random() *4);
    button3.setText(questions[randomArray][randomArray2+1]);

    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    int randomArray3 = (int) (Math.random() *4);
    button4.setText(questions[randomArray][randomArray3+1]);

    Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    int randomArray4 = (int) (Math.random() *4);
    button5.setText(questions[randomArray][randomArray4+1]);
```

The +1 just means the question will not be placed in the buttons. All I want help with is how I would go about removing the random selection from the options so that I dont have a question that has 2,3 or 4 buttons saying steve or 30 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your strings in an ArrayList, randomize the ArrayList, then simply keep removing the top entry from the ArrayList for each button.

```
mButton1.setText(mArrayList.remove(0));
mButton2.setText(mArrayList.remove(0));
```

Comment: Should the arraylist be kept in the same location as the array?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The ArrayList would be generated when you want to populate the buttons, and then discarded. You would only need to keep track of which answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the answers you want to display in an `ArrayList`, you can then use `Collections.shuffle()` to simply randomize the order. Then you would just put the answers in their views one by one and they will automatically be shuffled for you. By doing it this way, you don't have to worry about repeats, because you're only ever going to have one copy of each answer in your list. So it's just a matter of putting them one by one into the views in their newly randomized order.

Check this out...here's how it works:

```
ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
answers.add("dave");
answers.add("steve");
answers.add("john");
answers.add("carl");

for(int i=0; i<answers.size(); i++) {
    //answers in their original order
    Log.d("ANSWERS", answers.get(i));
}

Collections.shuffle(answers, new Random());

for(int i=0; i<answers.size(); i++) {
    //answers are now in a randomized order
    Log.d("SHUFFLED ANSWERS", answers.get(i));
}
```